# looping gridview using jquery is slow

Tags: jquery, loops, gridview

i have written below code to show hide rows of gridview using jquery but when there are more than 1000 rows in the grid. it shows below browser msg.

Error message: "A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly"

StartCount and EndCount could be any two values. e.g i want to show/hide 50 - 250 rows

```
var gvAccountReview = $('[id$=gvAccountReview]');

for (i = iStartCount; i < iEndCount; i++)
{
    if (chkImage.attr("name") == "minus")             
       $(gvAccountReview).find('tr:eq(' + i + ')').show();
    else                   
       $(gvAccountReview).find('tr:eq(' + i + ')').hide();
}
```

Please help me out.

Comment: This happens mostly if you are going into an infinite loop.

Comment: In this case loop is not going into an infinite as sometimes it is working fine and sometimes it is throwing error. another reason i could think is when the machine is slow. this error comes but i am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

did you verify the script causing the delay is the one you posted? If so, when is this loop triggered?

Comment: yes i did verify. this is the script which is causing error. basically i tried by commenting this code and it was working fine. i have used grouping functionality on my grid data. grouping is working fine. after the data is grouped in the grid i have used plus and minus image to collaspe and expand the rows using jquery. when i am doing that it is throwing this error.

Comment: @AmitGrover okay then I don't know from here. You should try and use a debugger or just make some console.logs and see at which time the script causes problems and if it is always the same time (time = iteration of the loop)

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest following, add console logs and observer if the counter is still moving or it is moving slow.

```
var gvAccountReview = $('[id$=gvAccountReview]');
console.log("Total : " +  iEndCount);

for (i = iStartCount; i < iEndCount; i++)
{
    if (chkImage.attr("name") == "minus")             
       $(gvAccountReview).find('tr:eq(' + i + ')').show();
    else                   
       $(gvAccountReview).find('tr:eq(' + i + ')').hide();
    console.log("Counter : " + i);
}
```

Hopefully this helps to resolve.

Cheers !!